# useCallback does not update on dependency in specific circustamces

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I have a `select` function that is initialized using `useCallback` using single dependency: `name`. Then I pass this function to some nested components to be called on `click` on a chart element. If I pass the function the way I do (see the example below), it turns out that dependency `name` of `useCallback` is never recognized (if I update input field by entering a new value, `console.log` outputs the old `name` when I click on the chart elements). Any ideas why React might behave this way? Does this have something to do with class instantiation and usage? The thing is that I tried using the same logic without `ChartWrapper` and `Chart` class instantiation with naked svg (without d3) - it works fine. So, the problem is somewhere in `ChartWrapper` or updated version of `Chart` using class instead of component function. Any ideas are welcome. Here is the full code of the minimal app that doesn't work:

App.js:

```
import React, {useState, useCallback} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import ChartWrapper from './ChartWrapper';

function App() {

  const [name, setName] = useState("some_name")

  const nameChangeHandler = (event) => {
    setName(event.target.value)
    console.log("Updated name to " + event.target.value)
  }

  const select = useCallback((node) => {
    console.log("selected " + node + " for name " + name)
  }, [name])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ChartWrapper onSelect={select} /><br />
      Name: <input name="name" value={name} onChange={nameChangeHandler}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

ChartWrapper.js:

```
import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Chart from './Chart';

const ChartWrapper = (props) => {
    const chartArea = useRef(null)
    const [chart, setChart] = useState(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!chart) {
            setChart(new Chart(chartArea.current, props.onSelect))
        }
        else {
            chart.update(props.onSelect)
        }
    }, [chart, props.onSelect])

    return (
        <div className="chart-area" ref={chartArea}></div>
    )
}

export default ChartWrapper
```

Chart.js:

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import React from "react";

class Chart {
  constructor(element, onSelect) {
    let vis = this
    vis.nodes = [2, 4, 6]
    vis.circleSize = 30;
    vis.distanceBetweenCircles = 5;

    vis.svg = d3.select(element).append('svg')
      .attr('width', vis.nodes.length * (vis.circleSize + vis.distanceBetweenCircles))
      .attr('height', vis.circleSize)

    vis.update(onSelect)
  }

  update(onSelect) {
    let vis = this;
    
    const circlesEnter = vis.svg.selectAll('circle').data(vis.nodes).enter()
    circlesEnter.append('circle')
      .attr('fill', "gainsboro")
      .attr('stroke', "grey")
      .style('cursor', 'pointer')
      .attr('cx', (d, i) => vis.circleSize/2 + vis.distanceBetweenCircles*i + vis.circleSize*i) 
      .attr('cy', vis.circleSize/2) 
      .attr('r', vis.circleSize/2) 
      .on('click', (event, d) => onSelect(d))

    const textsEnter = vis.svg.selectAll('text').data(vis.nodes).enter()
    textsEnter.append('text')
      .attr('text-anchor', "middle")
      .attr('dominant-baseline', "middle")
      .attr('font-size', "12")
      .style('cursor', 'pointer')
      .attr('x', (d, i) => vis.circleSize/2 + vis.distanceBetweenCircles*i + vis.circleSize*i)
      .attr('y', vis.circleSize/2)
      .text(d => d)
  }
}

export default Chart;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in using d3's [`enter()`](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/d3js/data-binding-in-d3js#enter) when performing updates - because the 3 circles already exist at that time, calls after `.enter()` won't add any new circle (and all those attr-s and onclick would be added only to the new circles).

You can fix it by drawing whole svg in your constructor and in update do just updating of click function.

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import React from "react";

export default class Chart {
  constructor(element, onSelect) {
    let vis = this
    vis.nodes = [2, 4, 6]
    vis.circleSize = 30;
    vis.distanceBetweenCircles = 5;

    vis.svg = d3.select(element).append('svg')
      .attr('width', vis.nodes.length * (vis.circleSize + vis.distanceBetweenCircles))
      .attr('height', vis.circleSize)

    const circlesEnter = vis.svg.selectAll('circle').data(vis.nodes).enter()
    circlesEnter.append('circle')
      .attr('fill', "gainsboro")
      .attr('stroke', "grey")
      .style('cursor', 'pointer')
      .attr('cx', (d, i) => vis.circleSize / 2 + vis.distanceBetweenCircles * i + vis.circleSize * i)
      .attr('cy', vis.circleSize / 2)
      .attr('r', vis.circleSize / 2)

    const textsEnter = vis.svg.selectAll('text').data(vis.nodes).enter()
    textsEnter.append('text')
      .attr('text-anchor', "middle")
      .attr('dominant-baseline', "middle")
      .attr('font-size', "12")
      .style('cursor', 'pointer')
      .attr('x', (d, i) => vis.circleSize / 2 + vis.distanceBetweenCircles * i + vis.circleSize * i)
      .attr('y', vis.circleSize / 2)
      .text(d => d)

    vis.update(onSelect)
  }

  update(onSelect) {
    let vis = this;

    vis.svg.selectAll('circle')
      .on('click', (event, d) => onSelect(d))
  }
}
```